# Is it possible to use Intel AMT to manage MacBooks?

Tags: administrator, firmware, macos

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-active-management-technology.html

I've heard MacBook intel chips are AMT-capable, but AMT isn't ever enabled so you can't actually use it. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Neither SCCM nor AMT are viable management suites for macOS. The former has some limited success doing anything, [AMT flat out isn’t well documented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306959/intel-management-engine-is-macos-vulnerable). One recent vulnerability seems to cover chipsets Apple uses, but there’s no Apple link amongst the 30+ vendor links to patch those vulnerabilities:

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025619/software.html

I would look to one of the traditional Mac MDM solutions to manage your Macs. I would also contact intel and Apple if you have a specific serial you want to check is or is not vulnerable and get an on the record answer.

As far as pragmatic solutions to manage macs, start with a free hosted MDM like https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/ and then you can evaluate if you want to pay for a hosted service as you grow or partner / build your Mac MDM solution from open source like https://www.munki.org/munki/

Comment: I know AMT is going to be limited. I just need the basics like controlling network access, remote shutdown and VNC.

Comment: AMT has been out since before 2008 (and that date is the support discontinuation date for the 1.0 version of this "product" for the D975XBX2 ethernet controller) so for over a decade, there's been zero documentation on macOS use of this. I understand you want to try anything, there's just no documentation of professionals actually using this and I haven't been able to dig up even amateur / prosumer use of this with Apple hardware. Sorry @user27636 this is as complete an answer I can provide. I'm sure someone will answer / edit if they can add more.